# Date as a Measure in SSAS

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

Currently i am working on SSAS Cube creation.I need to know whether date values can be a measure in the measure group.Measures are countable since date is constant and has a value, is it possible to include date as a measure?

Comment: This should work. However, you will probably use another aggregation than `sum`, like `max`, `min`, or `LastNonEmpty`.

Comment: so it is basically a non-aggregate measure with its own property ?

Comment: What do you mean by "with its own property"? And - depending on the purpose for using a date as measure - it would be aggregatable, but not with the standard aggregate function "sum", but with another one: Summing several dates does not make sense, but taking the newest (max) or oldest (min) of several dates is exactly what you want to have in many situations. If you want to have a date as a measure, then it should somehow be aggregatable, as that is the purpose of a measure normally. If you do not want to aggregate the data, then it would better be an attribute or a property of an attribute.

Comment: Thanks :) now i am clear in using date as a measure and by stating 'its own property' i wanted to know whether it will retain its data type as date or will it be just some value.

Comment: @FrankPI would you put the majority of your comment in as an answer, please? Thanks.